When does DTLS negotiation start in WebRTC?
I am implementing the WebRTC stack from scratch as a hobby project. I cannot understand when the DTLS negotiation is supposed to start? BEFORE or AFTER the candidate nomination is completed with a triggered check?
When I connected two Chrome clients in p2p and monitored the traffic on Wireshark, it seems that the DTLS client hello is sent before the candidate has been nominated, What I don't understand is why it establishes the DTLs before even knowing the actual nominated candidate pair.

What you are observing is most likely aggressive nomination described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245#section-8.1.1.2
DTLS starts once there is a candidate that is writable, why wait for nomination which takes some time.

Thanks for the info regarding aggressive nomination.sorry for the dumb question so if DTLS negotiated with any writable candidate and if at the end that candidate is not chosen as the final candidate to send media on then we do not need to re-negotiate DTLS right ?

Correct. The DTLS layer should treat ICE as a single virtual socket and not care that the underlying socket address changes.
